# Microservices Ecosystem: integrating Spring and Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I've been reading about microservices and deploying educational projects with Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. Now I want to step up to another level and start using `
Docker and Kubernetes as container and orchestrator. My doubt is, most microservices tutorial for Java are about Spring Cloud with Eureka and Zuul, but when you move to Kubernetes, you don't really need Eureka and Zuul, do you? If so, is there an orchestrator that fully integrates Spring Cloud system? Or, best bet is integrating Spring Cloud with Kubernetes and forgetting about Eureka and Zuul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes provides native support for service discovery and API gateway. So below technologies can be replaced:

- Netflix Eureka with Kubernetes Service
- Spring Cloud Config Server with Kubernetes config maps and secrets
- Spring Cloud Gateway with a Kubernetes Ingress resource

Below blogs provide more information on the above:

https://blog.christianposta.com/microservices/netflix-oss-or-kubernetes-how-about-both/

Comment: not so sure about the cloud gateway bullet, depending on your application, spring cloud gateway can do more than routing requests.